# Handlebars helpers with mongoose

Tags: node.js

I am trying to display data from a mongoose database.

Here is my code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('SafeUrls', function() { 

var data = '';

    UrlInfo.find({}, function(err, result){

                if(err){  }
                else{


                    for(var v = 0; v < result.length; v++)
                    {
                        data += '<span>' +result[v].URL + '</span><br>';
                    }   
                }

            });             

return data;
});
```

It always returns empty because the find function doesn't complete before the return happens. How can I get data displayed from the database without this happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Please share

Answer (score 0):

The callback function passed to `find()` in your code runs asynchronously. So you can't use `return` to send the value of `data` back to the calling function. Instead, you need to do whatever you want to do with `result` (and by extension, `data`) in the inner callback function.

If you need to notify an external function that the value of `data` has been set, you can emit an event using an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use asynchronous code inside the handlebars helpers since parsing a template is synchronous process. You need all the data ready before you call `Handlebars.compile()`

As @Trott said you can't get `data` filled the way you're expecting. You may see [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/141) discussion on supporting asynchronous helpers in handlebars.